# Any way to get IntelliJ features for Javascript in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, intellij-idea

IntelliJ is great for Javascript refactoring/expand/collapse/error reporting.

Currently have Visual Studio 2008 SP1, ReSharper 4.5.
Neither does what IntelliJ does [e.g. pointing out that a line is missing ';' at the end]

Can VS w/ReSharper do that?  Is there a specific setting?

EDIT:  I understand they are for different environments [Windows/Java].  I'm just asking if there is a way with VS/ReSharper to do the cool Javascript formatting that IntelliJ does.

Answer (score 2):

No.  These are some fundamental functionality differences between the two environments.  VS is aimed towards windows development (C#/VB/ASP.NET) while InteeliJ is aimed towards more java web development (Java/JavaScript).  Two different products, two different feature sets.